# Feeding a combo highchart from Google Spreadsheet or json

Tags: highcharts

I'm doing a combo scatter and line charts (it's a electoral poll tracker) following this example from HC docs:

```
series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Party1',
    data: [10.1,9.2,9.8]
}, {
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Party2',
    data: [6.5,6.5,6.8]
}, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Party1-tracker',
    data: [10.1,9.8,10.0]
}, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Party2-tracker',
    data: [6.5,6.5,6.6]
}]
```

On another document, I can make a chart from a Google Spreadsheet. I've followed this Jack Dougherty example: https://jackdougherty.github.io/highcharts-with-google-sheets/bubble.html

```
data: {
        // insert the key from your public Google Sheet
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '1fYJOd-2agLPg38qhblS8qoZGWGkKcK-3uTsMpf37Hys',
        // insert Google Sheet column headers (x, y, z...) to match column numbers (0, 1, 2...)
        seriesMapping: [{x: 0, y: 1, z: 2, name: 3, country: 4, category: 5}],
        complete: function(data) {
          categoriesIntoSeries(data);
          changeSeriesColors(data);
        }
      },
```

plus

```
  /**
   * Here, all data is split into categories depending on the 'category' property
   * Needed for correct legend display
   */
  function categoriesIntoSeries(data) {
    rows = data.series[0].data;
    data.series = [];

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      cat = rows[i].category;
      catExists = false;
      for (j = 0; j < data.series.length; j++) {
        if (data.series[j].name == cat) {
          // Add a data point to existing series
          data.series[j].data.push(rows[i]);
          catExists = true;
        }
      }
      if (!catExists) {
        // When category is encountered for the first time, create a series
        data.series.push({name: cat, data: [rows[i]]})
      }
    }
  }
```

What I've tried unsuccessfully is (maybe it's impossible) to connect each column from my spreadsheet to each 'series' element. Something like this:

```
{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'Party1',
    data: /*get data from spreadsheet column 1 or a json field*/
}
```

I'll be thankful if you can tell us if it's possible and, if yes, point me to some documentation or example on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seriesMapping` array for this. It should contain a mapping for every column from the sheet.

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/b45s1Luh/

```
  seriesMapping: [{
    x: 0, 
    y: 1 // first column series
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 2 // second column series
  }, {
    x: 0,
    y: 3 // third column series
  }]
}
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Comment: Thank you! I've now other problems, but this one seems fixed